# How do I terminate a 'Ping' without closing the command terminal window?

Tags: command-line, networking, ping

When I use the 'Ping' command in a terminal window, how do I terminate the ping?  I have pinged my router (192.168.1.1) and the results have displayed in the terminal window, but the program keeps running with no indication as to how to terminate.

I can end the command by closing the command terminal window, but I would rather keep it open so I can compare pings with different addresses.

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are three options:

- Manually interrupt the `ping` command using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, as described in @[steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/725826/367990).
- Use `ping`'s "count" option (`-c COUNT`) to send exactly COUNT pings and then terminate automatically, as described in @[bodhi.zazen](https://askubuntu.com/users/35795/bodhi-zazen)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/725827/367990).
- Use `ping`'s "deadline" option (`-w DEADLINE`) to run for exactly DEADLINE seconds and then terminate automatically.

---

Of course you can combine the three options. If you pass both a "count" and a "deadline" option, ping will terminate as soon as the first event occurs. And <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> works always anyway.

Here's an example with a "count" of maximal 10 pings and a "deadline" of 5 seconds, but which got terminated manually using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> after 3 pings (`^C`):

```
$ ping -c 10 -w 5 askubuntu.com
PING askubuntu.com (104.16.110.188) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 104.16.110.188: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=54.6 ms
64 bytes from 104.16.110.188: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=52.5 ms
64 bytes from 104.16.110.188: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=54.0 ms
^C
--- askubuntu.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 52.582/53.733/54.611/0.850 ms
```

Comment: Sometimes either the terminal eats CTRL C, or DNS query blocks, in that case you can use `CTRL Z` followed by `kill %1` to suspend the process and then kill it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to send a SIGINT (interrupt signal) to the `ping` process - see [Unix signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal)

Answer (score 3):

Either give ping a count with the -c option :

```
ping -c 4 google.com
```

Or use the keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to terminate the command.

Answer (score 1):

You should try  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to stop the processus.

Comment: @CharlesGreen , Actually this answer posted 6 minutes before the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

You can try <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to send an interrupt signal, it will terminate the program without closing terminal